# user_pictures & user_register variables

Tags: drupal, configuration, import, drupal-7, export

I'm trying to pragmatically set those 2 variables upon installing a site.

```
user_pictures (Disabling user pictures altogether) 
user_register (allowing visitors to register without admin)
```

I'm using Features with strongarm but no luck. Even with the feature enabled the options are wrong in the account settings.

Setting the variable manually with a script doesn't do the trick either, although the options show the correct checkbox as ticked, I still have to to the page a click "save configuration" to confirm the setting.

This goes for maaany other variables I'm tryign to set, and I'm not sure if this is possible but it would be nice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution which only solves part of my problem is to use Install profiles. The problem with those is that some variables still don't seem to take effect or work at all...

https://drupal.org/developing/distributions
https://drupal.org/project/profiler

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the intended behavior of the features module, according to [this old issue on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/927568):

> Say when developing a site, and set the settings at admin/user/settings for user_register. then you go live, later you decide to change the value, make a feature and strongarm that user_register variable then deploy that. The setting will still be in the database (as a variable), thus the feature is overridden.

The simplest solution is to not rely on features to set your variables on installation. It's much simpler to use `hook_install` anyway. I suppose we're only supposed to think of the Features module as a means of setting up or updating complicated configuration from the Features administration page, but not when the module itself is enabled or updated.

This will set the variables you describe for the `example` module:

```
function example_install() {
  variable_set('user_pictures', 0);
  variable_set('user_register', 1);
}
```

If other parts of your feature also aren't being set up correctly, perhaps you should try this instead:

```
function example_install() {
  // This will only revert 'variable' features. Include additional features as needed.
  features_revert(array('example' => array('variable')));
}
```